# List navigation (spinner) on the right side

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, android-spinner

I have tried so many tutorials, but I could not find article that would tell me how to create spinner in action bar (sherlock version), but on the right side.

Is there a way to do it? Do I need to create additional views and adapters? I just want to know easy way to create that spinner on the right side, nothing else, just it.

Answer (score 5):

You'll need to create a custom layout for the view containing the spinner. Inflate and place it on the action bar and you're good to go.

Here you have some sample code for this(this is what you do inside your activity to initialize and place your layout on the action bar):

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    final View spinnerView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_spinner, null);
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) spinnerView.findViewById(R.id.my_spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.spinner_items_array, R.layout.spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // Do whatever you want with your selected item. You can get it as: parent.getItemAtPosition(position); 
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {}
    });

    getSupportActionBar().setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_actionbar_logo));//set your actionbar logo
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME | ActionBar.DISPLAY_HOME_AS_UP | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE );

    LayoutParams layoutParams = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT; // set your layout's gravity to 'right'
    getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(spinnerView, layoutParams); //place your layout on the actionbar
```

Your layout should look something like this (layout_spinner.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Spinner
    style="@style/Widget.Sherlock.Light.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar"
    android:id="@+id/my_spinner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="right" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Your array stored in a res folder (spinner_items_array):

```
    <string-array name="spinner_items_array">
        <item>Item1</item>
        <item>Item2</item>
    </string-array>
```

The spinner custom item (spinner_item.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/cab_spinner_item"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textAlignment="inherit"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" /> <!-- Set whatever color you want for the text -->
```

And finally the drop-down list item (spinner_dropdown_item.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textAlignment="inherit"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
```

I hope this answer will help you!!
Good luck!

Comment: Great example, thank you. I was following your code and managed to get the spinner to be right aligned. The only thing that troubles me is that when I set this custom view (the spinner) to the actionBar, my actionBar title disappears. I have the ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE options set, but the title is still missing. Do you have any idea why this is happening? I want to have the both title and spinner in my action bar....

Comment: What OS are you targeting? With the above implementation you should have the Up icon, actionbar icon, title and spinner visible on the actionBar. These lines are doing the magic:        getSupportActionBar().setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_actionbar_logo));//set your actionbar logo 
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME | ActionBar.DISPLAY_HOME_AS_UP | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE );

Comment: I am trying this on an 4.4.2 Android device. Not working still... but +1 for making the spinner go to the right

Comment: Sandra, I just tried the above implementation and it worked perfectly(on same OS). Are you sure, you add a title to your activity? Or you're not removing it somewhere? I might be able to help you if you provide some code here.