# Can I add spinners to ActionBar or ActionMode in android?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, spinner, actionmode

1.Since in API 21 the method setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST) is deprecated.Which API replace it?

2.Can I set the spinner right-aligned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you obama.

Action bar mainly contains four functional areas. They are app icon, view control, action buttons and action overflow.

**App Icon** – App branding logo or icon will be displayed here.

**View Control** – A dedicated space to display app title. Also provides option to switch between views by `adding spinner` or tabbed navigation.

**Action Buttons** – Some important actions of the app can be added here.
Action Overflow – All unimportant action will be shown as a menu.

Check out the following diagram for complete overview about action bar.

[image]

With the API 21 the method `setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST)` is **deprecated**.

The best way to work with a spinner is to use a Toolbar like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">

    <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

You can find an example in the [Google IO 2014](https://github.com/google/iosched)

Comment: In my situation, it's better to add spinner in the right side(like the place "search"). And I want to keep the title.

Comment: Also, setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST) is deprecated, do you have some idea?

Comment: Take a look at my edit. In order to do such orientation, you must create your own layout. Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18723269/list-navigation-spinner-on-the-right-side